# Pandas Pivot change order of columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

How can I change the order of columns in a pivot function?

My inital table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTfAb.png) and using the command

```
df.pivot_table(index=['timestamp'], columns=['JI'], values=['X','Y','Z','RX','RY','RZ'])
```

leads to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ApVq.png). But I want all columns for one JI Index one after another, it should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVHc4.png). The reason for this is, that I want to be able to extract all Data for one specific JI easily.

Or is there any other function in pandas to create the wanted result?

Comment: [Doesn't work sadly](https://imgur.com/a/WcBeW)

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I thought you need to swap the levels.  You just need to sort by the level 1 instead of level 0.  `df_out.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort_level` with `level` and `axis` parameters:

```
df_out.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
```

Comment: I know it doesn't directly relate to my first question, but do you know how to (or have a link to resource) select certain rows / columns from a dataset of [this](https://imgur.com/a/YT5c2) form? Is this MultiIndex?

Comment: [Pandas MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) is where the documentation on how to select rows and columns with multiindex.  What you have in this dataframe is a multiindex column index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  While something like this

   `df.xs((0,0), level=('ID','JI'), axis=1)`

works as intended, I am wondering how to get multiple columns from the same key index, e.g. something like this

    `df.xs((0,[0,2]), level=('ID','JI'), axis=1)`